# Default image in Django model ImageField does't work

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a huge problem with default image in my django model, in model.ImageField. 
My users/models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
```

And my project/urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In my project/settings.py I have:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

On website, src of my image is (unknown)...
Every image I upload in my admin panel is ok. Just this default, when user has no image.

What is wrong with this? I done it once in the past and everthing worked.
Could you help me?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `profile_pics/default.jpg`? Note that this is the path in the media file, so by writing `default='default.jpg'`, you set it to a file in the `/media/` directory.

Comment: Could you post the output of your request (presumably from a broweser) to clarify for us why this is failing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks for an image `default.jpg` in the **`/media/`** directory. If the `default.jpg` is located in the `profile_pics/` subdirectory, you should specify as `default=…` parameter `profile_pics/default.jpg`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(
        default='profile_pics/default.jpg',
        upload_to='profile_pics'
    )
```

Comment: I changed the path, did the migration and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @lukos06: the old ones of course will still not work. What if you create a new profile?

Comment: @lukos06: are you sure the extension is `.jpg`, and not `.JPG`, `.jpeg`, etc.? What if you use `ls` in the directory?